# Renaming of Packages causes Dalvik format error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have recently imported a project into Eclipse, Then I have those packages renamed, but when I run and checked for the output, it display in the Android Console:

[2015-10-27 21:19:27 - SICT-Android] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.sun.jna.Native$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format.
....

at the end:

[2015-10-27 21:19:27 - SICT-Android] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2015-10-27 21:19:27 - SICT-Android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1

I would be glad for anyone who can help, thanks

Comment: What have you already tried to do?

Comment: I had updated the proguard in the Android SDK, but I still got the error..